# Is this a valid wsdl file?

Tags: soap, soap-client

I need to integrate with a very old service written in SOAP and has this wsdl file. I tried to use https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap for creating a soap client but it throws exception which is not very useful but after debugging into the its code, seems like it expect "message" to be present in the wsdl file (breaks at https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/lib/wsdl.js#L669). My question is - is the wsdl below valid? If yes how can i create a client for this file?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="LocateService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SOAPEndpoint_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization
                    xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
                    <http:BasicAuthentication
                        xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http"/>
                        <sp:TransportBinding
                            xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:TransportToken>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:TransportToken>
                                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:Basic256/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                <sp:Layout>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:Strict/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:Layout>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportBinding>
                        <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsdl:types/>
            <wsdl:portType name="ILocateWebService">
                <wsdl:operation name="ProcessLocates">
                    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/ProcessLocates"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="ProcessResponses">
                    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/ProcessResponses"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="GetLocateUpdates">
                    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/GetLocateUpdates"/>
                    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/GetLocateUpdatesResponse"/>
                    <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/GetLocateUpdatesLocateServiceFaultFault" name="LocateServiceFaultFault"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="GetConnectionDetails">
                    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/GetConnectionDetails"/>
                    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/GetConnectionDetailsResponse"/>
                    <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/GetConnectionDetailsLocateServiceFaultFault" name="LocateServiceFaultFault"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="LocateProcessingEnabled">
                    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/LocateProcessingEnabled"/>
                    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/LocateProcessingEnabledResponse"/>
                    <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateWebService/LocateProcessingEnabledLocateServiceFaultFault" name="LocateServiceFaultFault"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
            </wsdl:portType>
            <wsdl:portType name="ILocateRESTService">
                <wsdl:operation name="ProcessResponsesXml">
                    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateRESTService/ProcessResponsesXml"/>
                    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILocateRESTService/ProcessResponsesXmlResponse"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
            </wsdl:portType>
            <wsdl:binding name="SOAPEndpoint" type="tns:ILocateWebService">
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SOAPEndpoint_policy"/>
                <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
                <wsdl:operation name="ProcessLocates">
                    <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
                    <wsdl:input/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="ProcessResponses">
                    <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
                    <wsdl:input/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="GetLocateUpdates">
                    <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
                    <wsdl:input/>
                    <wsdl:output/>
                    <wsdl:fault name="LocateServiceFaultFault"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="GetConnectionDetails">
                    <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
                    <wsdl:input/>
                    <wsdl:output/>
                    <wsdl:fault name="LocateServiceFaultFault"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
                <wsdl:operation name="LocateProcessingEnabled">
                    <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
                    <wsdl:input/>
                    <wsdl:output/>
                    <wsdl:fault name="LocateServiceFaultFault"/>
                </wsdl:operation>
            </wsdl:binding>
            <wsdl:service name="LocateService">
                <wsdl:port name="SOAPEndpoint" binding="tns:SOAPEndpoint">
                    <soap12:address location="https://locatehubchi.qalab.net/locatehub.locateservice/LocateService.svc"/>
                    <wsa10:EndpointReference>
                        <wsa10:Address>https://locatehubchi.qalab.net/locatehub.locateservice/LocateService.svc</wsa10:Address>
                    </wsa10:EndpointReference>
                </wsdl:port>
            </wsdl:service>
        </wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the message is a required attribute on the wsdl:operation/wsdl:input element. Therefore this would not be a valid WSDL. And because there is no message defined it would be impossible to create a proper client based on the wsdl because you have no idea what message you would have to send.